# Se puede condicionar un evento sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo este evento

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhot` EVENT `prueba` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR STARTS '2018-11-23 16:35:00.000000' 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO UPDATE cat_marca as tabla_c 
SET tabla_c.precio = (SELECT tabla_c.precio * tabla_b.porcentaje 
FROM cat_concepto as tabla_a INNER JOIN cat_depreciacion as tabla_b ON tabla_a.id_depreciacion = tabla_b.id WHERE tabla_c.id_concepto = tabla_a.id_concepto) WHERE tabla_c.nombre_marca = 'neffos'
```

mi pregunta es se puede condicionar por ejemplo que actualice  los datos que cumplan un año registrados, pero que no  actualice los datos que tienen menos de un año ingresado?

Comment: En la forma en la que lo redactaste, parece que debe ser una condición en el where. Cuál es la dificultad para agregarla o qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Pense lo mismo que vos jachguate del where tambien de que si la fecha de creacion es igual a la misma fecha mas 1 en el año, hasta que me acorde del año bisiesto ahi si justo se crea el registro ese dia adicional del año no te lo actualiza hasta dentro de 4 años, asi q creo que va por programacion y condiciones por afuera, por ejemplo una tarea programada de windows que ejecute todas las noches un archivo php que este encargado de buscar todos los datos, comparar las fecha, guardar en un array los que se tienen que updater y dsp updatear todos juntos con la info que sea necesario

Comment: @Juan, tocayo, todo depende de como escribas la condición del `where`, pero eso que describes, no tiene por qué pasar. Un saludo.

Comment: Tenes razon, tal vez solo con un case de que si la fecha es 29/2 la cambie a 28/2 y ahi compare en el where, todo estaria en la misma consulta, pero bueno es otra cosa, cuando el usuario ponga que ha intentado se podra pensar mejor la respuesta.

Comment: Probe  con  el where, pero lo  que necesito  es que se ejecute anualmente  cada que se cumpla un año por cada fecha ingresada y claro solo alterando  el  campo  que pertenezca a esa fecha.  Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con un Set, Case

...

```
SET tabla_c.precio =CASE
 WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(CURDATE()), DATE(fecha_creacion))>=365
 THEN 
// el valor que tomara table_c.precio.
 END
```

...

En este caso el hará la edición solo cuando la diferencia entre la fecha de actual y la fecha de creación del registro supere 365 días o un año.